# Video conversion with FFMPEG and PHP working perfectly in localhost, and in Linux terminal, but not on website

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg, video-conversion

The title pretty much tells the whole story. Here's my entire code:

```
<?php 
$uploads_dir = 'original/';
$file_name = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$db_file_name = date("DMjGisY")."".rand(100000,999999);
$uploaded_file = $uploads_dir . $file_name;
$convert_status = ['mp4' => 0];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploaded_file)) {
    $ffmpeg = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg';
    
    // MP4
    $video_mp4 = $db_file_name . '.mp4';
    exec($ffmpeg . ' -i "' . $uploaded_file . '" -c:v libx264 "./converted/' . $video_mp4 . '" -y 1>convert.txt 2>&1', $output, $convert_status['mp4']);
    
    $vidmp4 = 'converted/'.$video_mp4.'';
    
    echo '<style>#video-upload-form{display: none;}</style>';
    echo '<div style="text-align: center;">';
    echo '<video style="max-width: 50%; height: auto;" controls>';
    echo '<source src="'.$vidmp4.'" type="video/mp4">';
    echo '</video>';
    echo '</div>';
  }
}
?>

<form id="video-upload-form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<!-- THIS FIXES 'CONFIRM FORM RESUBMISSION' -->
<script>
    if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
        window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
    }
</script>
```

When I put this on my website, the only change was to the 9th line - '$ffmpeg = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg';'. This is what I got when I ran the command, 'which ffmpeg'. I have beaten myself to death trying to figure this out. There has to be something in PHP or FFMPEG that is missing from my server. Please, can someone help me?

Comment: A log excerpt would help.

Comment: what is the `$output` value? mostly this happens because the different SAPIs is acting differently with ffmpeg

Comment: I really don't know. I've changed this script so many times that I must have left in in there by mistake. But the above script does work perfectly in localhost. I researched what you said about SAPI's and have no idea how to fix this problem.